# Is it possible to compile a Maven java project, ignoring java files which have errors and compiling those without errors?

Tags: java, maven

Question as in title.

There are large projects in development where not all files are in a complete state. I know you can `skipTests` but it seems like `fail_never` should allow the project to compile as far as it can rather than stopping at first compile failure.

Comment: I don't know answer to your question, but this is bad idea to have compilation errors in a project, no matter how big is it. Introduce CI or something to deal with the problem.

Comment: My question is clearly whether this can be done, not a question about practices. Why post if you don't know?

Comment: I hope it is impossible to do (that's the answer!), just to forbid the horrible practices.

Comment: @kan just curious, why is it a bad idea? Not that I think it isn't, but I've wondered the same thing as Jeff. If there's a dead class (like, wouldn't get loaded), and deleting it doesn't break the program, I've sometimes wondered how to just exclude it from compilation rather than commenting it out or deleting it. For sure I can see that having broken code would confuse other developers, but if Jeff is working alone (or with people who also feel similarly) and wants to have that sort of workflow, why is it bad?

Comment: @Roman If a class/code is dead - delete it. Or are you not using VCS??!

Comment: @kan I am, but to Jeff's point, he is working on building out some classes and the work is not completed. I presume he is using CVS/SVN or some other centralized VCS and he does want to commit frequently and often but the code is not always in a compilable state.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
    <build>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <failOnError>false</failOnError>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
   </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something that comforts me about Java is that, if there is a class file, the compiler has passed it. Java is still (last I checked) a strongly-typed language, and the primary purpose of that is to catch errors early. I would not want the situation of other languages where the output of compilation could exist even if there were a compiler error.

Without the class file for class A, then a class B that uses class A cannot compile correctly either. Again, this is by design, and a primary reason I like the language.

Given those two things, having a failed project "get as far as it can" does not seem useful to me. Modern IDEs will tell you if you have compile errors, and whether they are due to syntax or other, incomplete source files. What else could doing this give you?

Comment: I may have misunderstood Jeff's question, but (from my own moments of having such thoughts of whether it can be done) maybe he was referring to dead classes that don't get referenced anywhere, e.g. classes which can be deleted without breaking the code.

Comment: Possible, though the "not all files are in a complete state" suggests to me files that are to be completed later, not that they're 'dead' and no longer maintained. It still leaves the whole question at a "good practice" level; I guess there's no particular harm in leaving dead code around your project, but I certainly don't advise it. For one thing, it breaks your build 8>) .  Something else I suppose I should have said is that allowing your build process to generate errors that you "know" to ignore just results in people (yourself and/or others) who ignore build errors.

Comment: These are classes that just represent ideas that may or may not be implemented. I could comment out all the code in them or delete them but the easiest thing is to just leave them as is until I decide what I want to do.

Comment: Suggestion: create a directory/package tree just for classes that are not supposed to be in the build yet, similar to the "test" tree commonly found in eclipse and Netbeans projects. Separating them physically from the "src" tree will remove them from your build, and remind you and whoever else that they are not ready for a build.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `maven-compiler-plugin` configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
       <execution>
           <id>default-compile</id>
           <phase>compile</phase>
           <goals>
               <goal>compile</goal>
           </goals>
           <configuration>
               <failOnError>false</failOnError>
           </configuration>
      </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

It is a very bad practice though.